# Makefile only recompile changed files

Tags: c, makefile

I am trying to write a makefile but it does not do exactly what I want.
I have the following files:

**a.h, b.h, c.h, d.h, main.h**

**a_functions.c, b_functions.c, c_functions.c, d_functions.c, main.c**

**main.c** includes **main.h**

And every **x_functions.c** includes  **x.h**

I want make to recompile **only** the files that have been edited.

This is how my code looks like now:

```
CC = gcc
CFLAG = -Wall -Werror
OBJ = program1
CPPFLAGS += -MD -MP
SRC = $(wildcard *.c)
 
all: $(SRC:%.c=%.o)
    $(CC) $(SRC) -o $(OBJ)

-include $(SRC:%.c=%.d)
```

What do I need to change to make it work? I have tried to find an answer on google but I can't find something that works (or something that I understand how to use)

Comment: now Does it alway  recompile with `make` ?

Comment: http://make.mad-scientist.net/papers/advanced-auto-dependency-generation/ has a very good explanation on dependency generation.

Answer (score 0):

Your `all` target does not actually create a file called `all`. It creates a file `$(OBJ)`. You should rewrite your `Makefile` to let Make know this. Also, `CFLAG` should be `CFLAGS`.

```
CC = gcc
CFLAGS = -Wall -Werror
OBJ = program1
CPPFLAGS += -MD -MP
SRC = $(wildcard *.c)
 
.PHONY: all
all: $(OBJ)

$(OBJ): $(SRC:%.c=%.o)
    $(CC) $(SRC) -o $(OBJ)

-include $(SRC:%.c=%.d)
```

Instead of `-MD` you can also use `-MMD`. That option ignores system headers files, such as `stdio.h`, which are unlikely to change.

Comment: I have now tried this and get:
'program1
make:  program1: No such file or directory
make: *** [Makefile:13: all] Error 127'

Comment: You cannot remove the recipe to do the link.  Make's built-in rule for linking will apply **if and only if** you have a `.c` file with the same name as your executable.  E.g., if you want to build `program1` then you must have a `program1.c` file, which can be turned into a `program1.o` file, which can be linked into `program1`.  There is no `program1.c` file so the default link rule does not match.  Put back the explicit rule and it will work.

Comment: As to whether the `-MD -MP` options are right I can't remember: the options controlling dependencies are varied and I always have to go look them up.  The blog post in the comments above is a great place to learn though.

Comment: @MadScientist Of course. I have edited my answer.

Answer (score 0):

> I want make to recompile **only** the files that have been edited.

That is `make`'s standard behavior, and one of the original motivations behind its invention.  But in order for it to do that accurately, it needs correct and complete information about which targets are built from which sources, and how.

The basic reason why `make` recompiles all your sources on every run (some twice) is that the rule you provide doesn't give it a way to do differently:

- The only explicit rule given is for a target named `all`.  This is the default rule by virtue of being first, so `all` will be `make`'s goal target if you do not name a different one on the command line.
- The rule does not actually build a file named `all`, so it will always be considered out of date, and its recipe run.
- **The recipe *explicitly* compiles all the sources named in `$(SRC)`**.
- Object files corresponding to the sources are named as prerequisites, so they will be updated if they are out of date, but the rule does not use them.  As a result, some of the sources may be compiled *twice* -- once to create an (unused) object file, and once to create `program1`.

The minimum change needed to achieve your stated objective would be to make the rule for `all` a *link* rule instead of a compilation rule, by designating object files as the (only) inputs to the compiler. `make`'s automatic `$^` variable can help here:

```
all: $(SRC:%.c=%.o)
    $(CC) $^ -o $(OBJ)
```

`$^` expands to a space-separated list of all the rule's prerequisites (so all the `.o` files in this case) with any duplicates removed.  That will, therefore, use the previously-unused `.o` files instead of rebuilding the `.c` sources.  The `.o` files will be updated (only) at need, according to `make`'s built-in rule for building a `.o` file from a correspondingly-named `.c` file.

But that still leaves you with issues.  The one you will notice first is that although `make` does not any longer recompile unchanged sources, it *does* re-link the program on every run, even if none of the sources changed.  This is because the default (and only explicit) rule is for a target named `all`, but it does not actually build a target of that name.  Its recipe will therefore be executed on every run, unless you happen to drop a new-enough, unrelated file named `all` in the source directory, in which case the program won't be rebuilt even when it ought to be.

To correct that, you should change the existing `all` rule to have the program being built as its actual target:

```
$(OBJ): $(SRC:%.c=%.o)
    $(CC) $^ -o $@
```

(Note that when it appears inside a rule's recipe, the automatic `$@` variable expands to the name of the target for which the recipe was invoked.)

You could leave it at that, but if you want to have an `all` rule, too, then create one *without a recipe*, naming the actual program to be built as a prerequiste, and declare it phony:

```
.PHONY: all
all: $(OBJ)
# No recipe
```

That should precede the rule for building `$(OBJ)`.

Additionally, note that `make`'s built-in rules obtain various kinds of compiler flags from various standard variable names.  Your `CPPFLAGS` is one of them (for GNU `make`) but `CFLAG` is not.  You probably meant `CFLAGS`, instead.

Furthermore, as a matter of style, `OBJ` or `OBJS` is conventionally used to name object files, not programs.  Often, makefiles for building a single program don't use a variable to designate its name at all.  There is less convention for what to use if you do want a variable naming the overall program, but personally, I'd be inclined to use `PROG` or `PROGRAM`.

Overall, then:

```
CC = gcc
CFLAGS = -Wall -Werror
PROG = program1
CPPFLAGS += -MD -MP
SRC = $(wildcard *.c)
OBJ = $(SRC:%.c=%.o)
 
.PHONY: all
all: $(PROG)

$(PROG): $(OBJ)
        $(CC) $(CFLAGS) $^ -o $@

-include $(SRC:%.c=%.d)
```

Finally, I would suggest naming your sources explicitly instead of using `$(wildcard)`.  This is more conventional, and it protects you against a few potential issues. I make this an addendum, however, because I have given up on persuading people to see past the allure of using wildcards, as your makefile does.  I rest assured that those who use makefiles long enough will learn, in time.  Or not.